# Difference in work days between two dates

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated column to calculate the difference in work days between two dates based on a work day steering table.

In the work day steering table, the bank days are flagged as 0 and work days as 1.

What DAX formula should I use to create a calculated column to get the difference in work days between two dates?

Expected Result in yellow:
[image: Output]

Work day steering table:
[image: Work day steering table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the dates where `BankDay = 1`.

```
WorkDays_CalculatedColumn =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        WorkDaySteering,
        WorkDaySteering[BankDay] = 1
            && WorkDaySteering[Date] > Input[Ship Date]
            && WorkDaySteering[Date] <= Input[Delivery Date]
    )
)
```

Comment: Olson - Thanks, but I got an error: "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns can not be converted to a scalar value."

Comment: That's an odd error. Are you defining this as a calculated column on the Input table?